# continuous integration - build separated projects or build all in one?

Tags: continuous-integration, integration-testing, versioning, project-management

I'm working on a project that will have these applications:

```
- backend api   (nodejs)
- ios app       (objective-c)
- android app   (java)
- web site      (php)
- admin site    (php)
- client site   (php)
```

My question is about versioning and managing all this projects.

I'm thinking about two options:

**1) build each app saparately**

- Harder to test apps integrations
- If I change something in one app, I need to be careful with all other apps
- I need merge all apps changelogs to a single document

**2) put all apps into one single build**

- This seems good to generate a single changelog
- Maybe write tests to apps integrations?

--

So, what is some good practices for this case? Maybe option 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My vote goes to option 2. Much easier to 'carry' development across all its phases with a *monolithic* approach:

- simpler integration - all pieces are already integrated, everyone working on any piece of the overall project is on the same page, not in their own sandbox (**true** continuous integration, if you want) - very important if you also plan to use agile methodologies
- integration testing no longer has to be a separate activity, you can do it
  part of the regular CI process since you can test all pieces together (possibly with a single combo testbed instead of dedicated testbeds for each piece - lower costs)
- simpler coherent/consistent source code control (even if the pieces have their own
  repos, they can be managed together in a monolithic style like I
  suggested in this Q&A:
  [Build dependencies and local builds with continuous integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30453983/build-dependencies-and-local-builds-with-continuous-integration/30530140?noredirect=1#comment49162246_30530140)
- possibly faster overall builds (different builds can use idle cycles
  in other builds which is harder to orchestrate when they are
  independent - they could potentially be better *"packed"*, leading to
  cost reduction on build resources)

Comment: I agree with everything you said. Is this a commom practice in real world? Build different apps into single deploy package. I'm looking for some articles to read about this, but found nothing

Comment: Not common yet (from the implementation prospective). Multiple apps in a single deploy pkg: fresh/initial linux distributions, almost every complex/advanced embedded system for which installing or upgrading is `monolithic` (for exampe computing/storage/networking/military equipment). Actually it doesn't `need` to be a *single* deploy package (unless by that you really mean a set of more or less related packages which just happen to be deployed together). The concepts are here: http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html

Answer (score 0):

I would absolutely not go with option 2. Continuous integration was termed by Grady Booch back in the early 90's. Today, they want to use the term Continuous Delivery. I say we should have used Continuous Improvement the whole time. Anyhow, you want to be able to deliver, deploy, put into production an application, a project, "a" deliverable. You absolutely do not want to mix applications. You could have the need to deploy one application to production and something is wrong with another application. Or you just did a very quick fix to a single application and you want to take it through the process to delivery today. I would not choose option 2 for these reasons.